# Emacs 29 - Error (use-package): rg/:catch: install not supported in nil

Tags: use-package, ripgrep

Here my init.el

```
(use-package rg
  :ensure t
  :ensure-system-package rg)
```

In Emacs 27 it's work just fine.

But I removed Emacs 27.1 and installed Emacs 29.1

And now when start Emacs 29.1 I get error:

```
⛔ Error (use-package): rg/:catch: install not supported in nil
```

Comment: You probably had some setup in the old version that you forgot about. See [:use-package-ensure-system-package](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages//doc/use-package.html#use_002dpackage_002densure_002dsystem_002dpackage) in the `use-package ` manual.